# Unable to recover BTRFS partition, what to do?

Tags: linux, data-recovery, btrfs, rescue

Using btrfs check:

```
$ sudo btrfs check --progress /dev/nvme0n1p7
[sudo] password for repair: 
Opening filesystem to check...
checksum verify failed on 24708644864 wanted 0x00000000 found 0xb6bde3e4
checksum verify failed on 24708644864 wanted 0x00000000 found 0xb6bde3e4
checksum verify failed on 24708644864 wanted 0x00000000 found 0xb6bde3e4
bad tree block 24708644864, bytenr mismatch, want=24708644864, have=0
ERROR: cannot read chunk root
ERROR: cannot open file system
repair@pop-os:~$
```

Using btrfs rescue

```
 sudo btrfs rescue chunk-recover -y /dev/nvme0n1p7
Scanning: DONE in dev0                        
kernel-shared/free-space-tree.c:706: remove_free_space_extent: Assertion `key.type == BTRFS_FREE_SPACE_EXTENT_KEY` failed, value 0
btrfs(+0x185e9)[0x563ee25945e9]
btrfs(+0x1a0bf)[0x563ee25960bf]
btrfs(+0x1a0d3)[0x563ee25960d3]
btrfs(remove_from_free_space_tree+0x16e)[0x563ee25a8b74]
btrfs(btrfs_run_delayed_refs+0x456)[0x563ee25a913d]
btrfs(btrfs_commit_transaction+0x3f)[0x563ee25b0cb7]
btrfs(btrfs_recover_chunk_tree+0x1f4e)[0x563ee25eea8a]
btrfs(+0x72e83)[0x563ee25eee83]
btrfs(main+0x328)[0x563ee2593ee8]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90)[0x7ff392e29d90]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x80)[0x7ff392e29e40]
btrfs(_start+0x25)[0x563ee2593f25]
Aborted
```

I already have btrfs-maintenance installed which should run snapshot using copy-on-write capabilities, but I wasn't able to find it.

What should be done here?

Comment: If the goal is *data recovery* running in-place file system repair tools is never a good idea. Please clarify if you need to recover the data.